How to navigate desired URL after Azure AD Login using MSAL angular
We are using Azure AD Authentication to validate users using MSAL after successful verification it is navigating to configured redirect URL.
For example:
redirect URL:

http://localhost:4200/

This URL is configured in App registration under Azure portal as Single Page Application.
Here it will navigate Azure ad login page after successful login it will navigate to above redirect URL.
Problem:
Now if user is trying to access specific URL as mentioned below (If user is not authenticated)

http://localhost:4200/data/100

User should authenticate using Azure AD. Them, after successful authenticate it should navigate to user requested URL for example above URL:

http://localhost:4200/data/100

But it always going to configured redirect URL i.e.:

http://localhost:4200

How to handle this type of scenario to navigate to desired URL?
`export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.clientId,
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenatId`,
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.SessionStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    }
  });
}`


One option could be is to store the url (session storage is an option) that the user was on before they authenticate and then navigate the user to that stored url after they successfully authenticate.

What i have done is "redirectUrl: window.location.origin".
